# MariaDB/MySQL docker image does not populate the db in the init script

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

```
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.5.8-focal
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .data/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
      - .docker/mysql/init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
```

having an init script.sql

```
CREATE DATABASE 'biostar';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'172.18.0.3' identified by 'biostar';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'biostar'@'172.18.0.3' identified by 'biostar';
```

expected:
a db with name biostar

actual:
no extra db, just the default ones

Comment: where is `script.sql` located?  Is it in `${PWD}/.docker/mysql/init`?

Comment: yes! it's there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that might be causing your issue.

First, `CREATE DATABASE 'biostar';` is incorrect syntax -- you need to use backticks and not single-quotes

Second, `script.sql` needs to be in the `.docker/mysql/init` folder (and the `.docker` folder needs to be in the same folder as your `docker-compose.yaml`, or you should specify a full path that begins with `/`)

Comment: quotes worked, but the problem was a prefix with ./ was missing